# How to add the new command bar button at the end of the other menu using spfx ? like after flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

How to add the new command bar button at the end of the other menu using SPFx? like after flow.

My new button(eviewer) is getting added after export to excel. I want to be added after end of flow.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible.

You can get more info on this GitHub issue and a link to the related user voice entry

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4204